# Hand tiling polyiamond puzzle. Non-trivial

Tags: no-computers, tiling, polyiamond

Group these 30 polyiamonds into five sets of six, then use each set of six to make five different convex shapes. There are some repeated polyiamonds, no set of six may contain a duplicate. The convex shapes must be completely covered with no gaps or overlaps. The pieces may be rotated and/or flipped.

This may be a significant effort, but using a computer would turn it into a trivial exercise. Partial answers will be scored simply by the number of completed convex shapes out of a max of 25.

[image]